# Is there a derivation of the linear regression equation from statistical principles?

Tags: statistics

Let us say that we have the equation $y = ax + b$ where $a = \frac{rs_{x}}{s_{y}}$ and $b = \bar{y} - a\bar{x}$. Where does $a$ and $b$ come from? How do statisticians reason their "derivation" if there is one?

Answer (score -1):

See [Ordinary Least Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) and [Simple Linear Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression) at Wikipedia.